# In C++, how can I create an instance of zoned_time as a class member?

Tags: class, timezone, variable-assignment, c++20, c++-chrono

I'm new to C++ and am exploring the use of timezones in chrono, specifically zoned_time.
I have only one issue with it: I want to use an instance of zoned_time as a member in a class, but no matter how I alter the syntax, the compiler doesn't like it.

```
#include <chrono>

#pragma once
class Event
{
private:
    std::chrono::zoned_time tz;
public:
    Event();
};
```

I've created a header file containing the code above, but it says the argument list for the class template is missing. I assume that means it wants me to initialize it, but I don't want to because it's a header file. As I said, I messed around quite a bit with the syntax of tz, combined with a good bit of research. Unfortunately, since I'm new to the language I really don't know what to look for online.

So my goal here is to be able to create a typed container within Event which will store the zoned_time information. I'm not picky on how I achieve that goal (I suspect some black-magic pointer trickery will be the solution). Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message mentions the word "template", indicating it's not about constructor arguments (initializer), but about generic type arguments (template parameters).

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/zoned_time this class is declared as:

```
template <
    class Duration,
    class TimeZonePtr = const std::chrono::time_zone*
> class zoned_time;
```

So it seems like you need a duration type to use (there is a default for the time zone pointer type). So your line should probably say something like

```
    std::chrono::zoned_time<std::chrono::seconds> tz;
```

Comment: Or pass `std::??_clock::duration`.

Comment: `std::chrono::zoned_time<std::chrono::system_clock::duration> tz;`